# FORTRAN code for logarithmic energies function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I need to write a FORTRAN code for the logarithmic energies function
\begin{equation}
H=-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}\ln{|x_i-x_j|}.
\end{equation}
where {${x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n}$} is a set of point on the unit sphere,
and || is the distance between two points.

Actually I wrote a code in python but I face some difficulties in translating to FORTRAN, here is the python code which might help you to understand the function

```
class SphericalCords(object):
  def __init__(self, phi, theta, r=1.):
    self.r = r
    #self.phi = phi
    #self.theta = theta
    self.phi =phi
    self.theta = theta

  def distance(self, other):
    v1 = self.translate_to_euclidian()
    v2 = other.translate_to_euclidian()
    distance = np.sum(np.square(np.array(v1) - np.array(v2)))**(0.5)
    return distance

  def translate_to_euclidian(self):
    x = np.sin(self.theta) * np.cos(self.phi)
    y = np.sin(self.phi) * np.sin(self.theta)
    z = np.cos(self.theta)

    return (x, y, z)

def HL(x):
 nof_row = len(x)/2
 acc = 0.
 for i in range(nof_row):
    xi_phi, xi_theta = x[i*2:i*2+2]
    xi = SphericalCords(xi_phi, xi_theta)
    for j in range(i+1, nof_row):
        xj_phi, xj_theta = x[j*2:j*2+2]
        xj = SphericalCords(xj_phi, xj_theta)
        acc += -np.log(xi.distance(xj))
 sol=acc  
 return sol
```

Comment: Have you started writing any of the FORTRAN implementation? Might have more luck getting assistance if you've written some of it. Maybe some boilerplate?